# submit form via jquery on select change event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

i am trying to submit a form via Jquery when change event occurs in select field like this:

```
$('select#slc_level').change(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
console.log('changed')
$('form#formLevel').submit();
```

But, it seems Jquery can not capture the event. No errors message.
I have three 'widget' in the form but the select field is in level 'widget'.
Curiously, Jquery can to capture change event on input file field in digital object widget in another form that i have in this page.
The whole code in my page is:

```
<div class='col-md-3'>
<div class="widget">
  <!-- Level widget -->
  <h4 class="text-info">Níveis</h4>
  @if(count($collection->collections) > 0)
    <ul class="list-group">
    @foreach($collection->collections as $sub_collection)
      <li class="list-group-item">{{$sub_collection->name}}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
    <br>
  @else
    <p class="text-muted">Nenhum cadastrado</p>
  @endif
    <form method="post" action="{{route('collection.form_level')}}" id="formLevel">
    <select id="slc_level" name="level_id" class="custom-select" autofocus>
      <option>Selecione ...</option>
      @foreach($levels as $level)
      <option value="{{ $level->id }}">{{ $level->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="collection_id" value="{{$collection->id}}">
  </form>
</div>
<hr>

<!-- Digital Object widget -->
<div class="widget">
  <h4 class="text-info">Objeto Digital</h4>
  @if(count($collection->objects) > 0)
    <ul class="list-group">
    @foreach($collection->objects as $object)
      <li class="list-group-item">{{str_limit($object->path,20)}} - {{$object->type}} - {{round(Storage::size($object->path)/(1024*1024),2)}}MB
        <a id="{{$object->id}}" href="#" class="delobject text-danger" title="Remover item">(x)</a>
      </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
    <br>
  @else
    <p class="text-muted">Nenhum cadastrado</p>
  @endif
  <form method="post" action="{{route('object.attach')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formObject">
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="path">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Escolher arquivo</label>
  </div>
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="collection_id" value="{{$collection->id}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="jpeg">
  </form> 
</div>
<hr>

<!-- Dimension widget -->
<div class="widget">
  <h4 class="text-info">Dimensão e suporte</h4>
  @if(count($collection->dimensions) > 0)
    <ul class="list-group">
    @foreach($collection->dimensions as $dimension)
      <li class="list-group-item">{{$dimension->name}}, ({{$dimension->size}}) {{$dimension->type}}
        <a id="{{$dimension->id}}" href="#" class="deldimension text-danger" title="Remover item">(x)</a>
      </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
    <br>
  @else
    <p class="text-muted">Nenhum cadastrado</p>
  @endif        
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dimensionModal">Inserir</button>
</div>
<hr>

<!-- Action widget -->
<div class="widget">
  <h4 class="text-info">Operações</h4>
  <a href="{{route('collection.edit',['collection_id'=>$collection->id])}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-block">Editar</a>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" id="btDelCollection" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" >Excluir</button>
  <a href="{{route('collection.publish',['collection_id'=>$collection->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">{{($collection->published)?'Não publicar':'Publicar'}}</a>
</div>
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#slc_level").change(function(){
    $('#formLevel').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Jquery `on` Method

```
$(document).on("change",'#slc_level',function(){
  $("#formLevel").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont need to put select#slc'_level

```
$('select#slc_level').change(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
console.log('changed')
$('form#formLevel').submit();
```

you can directly put the id
like

```
$('#slc_level').change(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
console.log('changed')
$('#formLevel').submit();
```